# Can I change MIT license to a proprietary license?

Tags: licensing, open-source-software

I have an open-source project licensed under MIT. Can I change the license to a proprietary license? (not double licensing) What if I don't want to distribute it anymore and want to move to a proprietary licensing? (I understand what fork of MIT code still be alive).

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our [tour page](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Are you the copyright holder of *all* the code (including patches)?

Comment: Some PR was merged before. I’m the original author.

Comment: The MIT license specifically states that sublicensing is permitted. I don't know if a sublicense could be written in a way that nullifies all or parts of the original licence. I don't know if you consider a sublicense to be a "dual license". The MIT license uses the term “Software” but does not state if that is only source code and documentation or binaries too.